# Finding derivatives for a Cauchy-Euler ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm having some trouble following along with the reduction of the Cauchy-Euler equation into a linear one with constant coefficients. I've been trying to follow along with the work [here](https://www.utdallas.edu/studentsuccess/mathlab/PatricksPDFs/euler.pdf), but I don't seem to understand their reasoning for the derivative substitutions. (All the work replicated here is on the first page.)

Given the general form of the homogeneous second-order Cauchy-Euler ODE,
$$ax^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+bx\frac{dy}{dx}+cy=0$$
we use the substitution $x=e^t$. So,
$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=e^t=x$$
So far so good.

Naturally, we want to find expressions for the derivatives of $y$ w.r.t. $x$ in terms of the derivatives of $y$ w.r.t. $t$. Noticing that we have $x\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ in the ODE, the author multiplies $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ by $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, and so
$$\color{red}{\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dy}{dx}}=x\frac{dy}{dx}~~\implies~~\color{red}{\frac{dy}{dt}}=x\frac{dy}{dx}$$
I'm not getting why these red terms are the same. Why can we say that the $dx$'s cancel out like in the expression $\dfrac{2}{3}\times\dfrac{5}{2}=\dfrac{5}{3}$?

For the moment, let's continue on to the second derivative. Differentiating the above w.r.t. $x$, we get
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{dy}{dt}\right]=\frac{dy}{dx}+x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$
and as before, we multiply by $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=x$ to get
$$\color{blue}{\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{dy}{dt}\right]\frac{dx}{dt}}=x\frac{dy}{dx}+x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{dy}{dt}+x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$
and somehow, the LHS is equivalent to $\color{blue}{\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}}$. How? Is it "legal" to just cancel the differentials and treat them like numbers in fractions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here we have a classic case of "forgot to write all variables, got a ton of questions".

Short answer - we don't cancel the factors (as in red), we use the derivative of composite function.

Long (more rigorous) answer - we introduce a function $z(t)=y(e^t)$. We derive it with respect to $t$ and obtain $z'(t) = y'(e^t)(e^t)'=y'(e^t)e^t$. Here, it is important to say $y'(e^t)$ stands for "the derivative of the function $s\to y(s)$ taken in the point $e^t$".

Then again, we derive it the second time and obtain that $$z''(t) = y''(e^t)e^{2t}+y'(e^t)e^t.$$ Now we use the DE on $y$ by substituting $x=e^t$ and get
$$a(z''(t) - z'(t))+bz'(t)+cz(t)=0.$$This equation is linear in $z$, has constant coefficients, everything is fine. We find the solution, then change the variables: $t=\ln x$.